# GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE resize behavior with PythonMagick

Tags: python, image, opengl, image-processing, imagemagick

Is it possible to resize an image with PythonMagick in the same way GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE works for texture mapping in OpenGL, where the border colors are extended like this?

[image: GL_CLAMP]